# How is the verify callback used in the API?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

While going through the `API` documentation of `passport-local`, it is mentioned that the strategy requires a verify callback.
Below is the example that is provided.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Here, `.verifyPassword(password)` is used as a callback?
Link for API is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local).

And If I want to give `email` instead of `username` then how should I approach this?

Comment: No, it's a simple method call to verify the password. You might see that better once you start to indent and format your code properly

Comment: The verify callback in this code is this function: `function(username, password, done) { ... }`

Comment: ok got it..thanks can you answer my second question which is the last line of the question. @robertklep

Comment: @AdityaJain https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters

Comment: thanks.. :) @robertklep

Answer (score 1):

1) user.verifyPassword(password) - synchronous function.

2) By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named 
   username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, 
   options are available to change the defaults:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```